# Separating strings into one list to remove duplicates

Tags: r, string, list, duplicates, read.csv

I have a large text file (50,000 rows) I'm trying to remove duplicates/find unique words from

The rows/strings in the CSV vary such that three lines could look like the following:

```
I like cars
Ford
Cars go fast
```

I would like to first separate each row/string and then combine them so I would get the following list from above:

```
I
like
cars
Ford
Cars
go 
fast
```

Once that list is complete it should be easy to change the cases of each word and then remove duplicates leaving a unique list of all words in the document.

Some rows are paragraphs and thus Excel just can't handle the job. I'm guessing `paste` and `paste(unique())` may be useful but I'm having trouble using `read.csv` to get the words from the document in the desired format.

These paragraphs may include punctuation, numbers, and random characters like @, so may need to transform the strings first.

EDIT:

3 methods that work, but different results, here is a link to the csv, any insight on why results are different would be appreciated.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=61FAC513EBF4A4B9!296&authkey=!AMsiIuW4lCD_qrs&ithint=file%2ccsv

Comment: you can dos something like `unlist(strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE))` (maybe will need an `as.character` transformation in between. Though a `dput` of your data could be helpful too probably.

Comment: I've managed to get either a table of 25000 obs of one variable (where each variable is a string which can either be a word or paragraph) or a table of 530000 obs of 62 variables where 62 is the largest number of words (delimited by space) in any paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `scan`

```
df1 <- data.frame(words= unique(scan(text=as.character(df$s), what="", sep=" ")))
df1
#  words
#1     I
#2  like
#3  cars
#4  Ford
#5  Cars
#6    go
#7  fast
```

---

Or a faster approach would be

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(words = unique(unlist(stri_extract_all(df$s, regex="\\S+"))))
```

Comment: Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  invalid 'text' argument

Comment: @OliPaul  I am not getting any error.  But, I also provided another method with `str_extract_all`

Comment: I will try that - I didnt mention within each string there may be other other characters such as @ as well as numbers and punctuation.

Comment: @OliPaul  Perhaps you can use `\\S+` instead of `\\w+` as I updated the post.

Comment: 128000 obs of 1 variable. I believe using view, that this has worked. Thanks!

Comment: I should be able to manually do this, but is there a way within this function to remove punctuation. At the minute records and records. and records, are all unique. I understand having different characters may complicate this as it wont always be clear when the character is punctuation or not!

Comment: @OliPaul Can you show an example to make this clear as I am not very sure about the pattern

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you read the original data into a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(s = c('I like cars', 'Ford', 'Cars go fast'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
             s
1  I like cars
2         Ford
3 Cars go fast
```

You can create your new result data frame as follows:

```
newdf <- data.frame(words = unlist(strsplit(df$s, ' ')))
newdf
  words
1     I
2  like
3  cars
4  Ford
5  Cars
6    go
7  fast
```

Comment: dfv1$x is 25000 obs of 1 variable. using the above I got: Error in strsplit(dfv1$x, " ") : non-character argument

Comment: Can you check the `str(dfv1)`? It expects character classes. Did you read with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as I show?

Comment: 'data.frame': 25605 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: Factor w/ 20136 levels "'Side by Side'

I did: dfv1=data.frame(x=vac2$VAC_DSCRPN, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: So...`x` is a factor. Convert it to character using `as.character()`.

Comment: df2<- data.frame(as.character(dfv1$x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
 df3 <- data.frame(words= unique(unlist(strsplit(df2$y, ' '))))
Works thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to split the string, have a look here:

"How to Split Strings in R"
By Andrie de Vries and Joris Meys from R For Dummies
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-split-strings-in-r.html

To split this text at the word boundaries (spaces), you can use strsplit() as follows:

```
strsplit(yourtext, " ")    # Split using spaces as boundaries
```

To find the unique elements of your list, you can use the unique() function:

```
unique(strsplit(yourtext, " "))
```

So there won't be duplicates any more in the result.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `cSplit()` from `splitstackshape`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, 1, sep = " ", direction = "long")

#     V1
#1:    I
#2: like
#3: cars
#4: Ford
#5: Cars
#6:   go
#7: fast
```

Comment: I did d2 <- cSplit(dfv1,1,sep= " ", direction= "long") and then d3<-data.frame(words=unique(d2)) and recieved 194000 whereas 128000 from the method below. Any insight?

Comment: Hard to solve issues that cannot be reproduced using **your** example.

Comment: The stringr method returned 213000 results. This data is public so I could upload the csv actually - I'm used to sensitive data but this is public

Comment: Seems like the way spaces are handled differ

Answer (score 1):

I would put all the words into a character vector, using the stringr package for convenience, like this:

```
tempdata <- read.csv("temp.csv",sep=",",skip=-1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=FALSE)

library(stringr)

listrows <- str_split(tempdata$V1,pattern=" ")
allwords <- unlist(listrows)
```

Comment: Did this then data.frame(unique(allwords)) and got 213000 results. This worked too, however all three methods return different results. Thanks